# Core dumped while running C recursion program

Tags: c, recursion

When I run the following C program the compiler shows segmentation fault(core dumped). I don't understand why is this and how can I retrieve this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int power(int x, int n)
{
  if (n = 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return x * power (x, n - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
  int x=3,n=4;
  printf("the answer is:%d\n",power(3,4));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: You are victim of typical assignment error in if statement. When comparing variable with constant, try to use `if (0 == n)`. In this case, if you do `if (0 = n)` you will face error.

Answer (score 7):

`if (n = 0)` is an ineffective recursion blocker, as it *assigns* `0` to `n` and evaluates to `0`. So currently the function calls itself *ad infinitum* which results in a core dump on your platform.

Did you mean `if (n == 0)`, or, better still `if (!n)`?

Reasonable compilers will issue a warning in such instances. Do you have them switched off?

Comment: Good programming practice when comparing variable with constant is to use constant first in statement, so similar to `if (0 == n)` which prevents mistakes of assignment.

Comment: @tilz0R: Indeed, some folk swear by *Yoda expressions*. Personally I dislike them.

Comment: There is also `if(!n)` and `if (n <1)` BTW for *negative* values of `n` the power could also be defined (but for integers it will mostly be zero)

Answer (score 4):

you are doing typo mistake I guss at line **if (n = 0)** instead of **if (n == 0)**

```
int power(int x, int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return x * power (x, n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type
"if (n = 0)"
It means that you are assigning a value to The variable n.
The operator "==" means that you are comparing the value at the left hand side with the right hand side.
So replace the = with ==

Comment: This does not add anything that have not been stated in previous answers.